# Passing a Variable into a Linux command

Tags: linux, shell

I created a shell script that takes an argument (i.e. $1 ). I'm trying to see if you can pass the argument from the command line.  In the below command I look to see if the shell script exist and if it does, execute it.  I'm looking to see if it's possible to pass a variable after the -exec that will replace the $1 in the script.  Any help would be great.

```
find -name yes.sh -exec {} +

find -name yes.sh -exec < argument > {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

`<` and `>` are for I/O redirection, not arguments. Arguments are simply placed after the command name.

```
find -name yes.sh -exec {} "$1" \;
```

Comment: sorry my bad, the < argument > in my command was just to show where I was trying to put the argument - probably not a good idea seeing as the < > are linux commands - Thanks